# Opposite of overflow: hidden? Is it possible?

Tags: css, overflow, parent

So when you declare `overflow: hidden` on a parent div, the portions of its children that are sticking out of the parent are hidden. Is the opposite possible? Where only the parts that sticking out are actually visible and the parts that are *within* the parent are hidden?

Answer (score 6):

I have that problem using bulma then I fixed it with--

```
{
  overflow:visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put a wrapper on the top of the div 
And hide the upper display leaving the rest for the display

```
<div class="cover"></div>
<div class="display"></div>

div.cover{
  Position:absolute:
  Height:300px;
  Width: 100%;
  Background:red;
}
div.cover{
  Height:500px;
  Width: 100%;
  Background:black;
}
```

Although what u want to ask isn't syntactically correct .